# When does an application get an "auto generated" deploy

Tags: commcare

I've noticed that an application has a release with a comment "Auto-generated by a phone update". What does that mean and when does it happen?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of CommCare version 2.34, users have the ability to update to the "latest saved state" of their app, without having to create a build first. (This is intended to streamline the process of iterative testing/debugging of a CommCare app). When CommCare HQ receives an update request of this nature, it simultaneously returns the information needed for an update to the user *and* kicks off a build in the background, so that the user can come back to the app version they updated to later. This is the build that you are seeing above.

I would also encourage you to read [this page](https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/Update+Target+Options), which has full details on the different update target options in CommCare and how to set them.